# Handling eventhandlers and suppression

Tags: c#

I am not too sure how to go about this. I do not have a great deal of experience with dealing with the filesystemwatcher class. If a similar question has been asked and answer, my apologies for the duplicate.

**Background/Purpose:** I have a class called folderobj that acts as a representation of the location that will be watched by filesystemwatchers. There are multiple folderobjs so there will be multiple filesystemwatchers. Each of these filesystemwatchers looks if the contents were created, changed or renamed. I have a list of folderobjs and a list of filesystemwatchers. As folderobjs get removed so do the filesystemwatchers. The project is on github so I can share if needed, but I included the relevant code below.

**Problem:** If another program is adding files to one of the folder paths, it is possible that it may create and modify the file causing the eventhandlers all to activate. My program is working as excepted when I manually copy a file into the folder or rename on its own (single action on a file). Program im using is a torrent client. So I believe this has to do with the nature of how the file is being created/modified by the torrent client. How can I modify my code so that if more than one event is triggered or will be triggered, that it will only fire once?

**Possible solution:** in NewFileWatcher I can -= all of the eventhandlers from .created, .changed, .renamed and at the end += all of them back. However, I do not know if this is more of a workaround rather than the "proper" way to handle this situation. Can anyone share their thoughts?

```
#region FileSystemWatcher
    private FileSystemWatcher InitializeFileSystemWatcher(FolderObj newFolder)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher newFileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = newFolder.Path,
            Filter = "*.*",
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
        };

        newFileSystemWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(NewFileWatcher_Handler);
        newFileSystemWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(NewFileWatcher_Handler);
        newFileSystemWatcher.Renamed += NewFileWatcher_Handler;

        newFileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return newFileSystemWatcher;

    }

    public void NewFileWatcher_Handler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

         FileSystemWatcher sentBy = (FileSystemWatcher) sender;
        sentBy.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        var dirName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sentBy.Path);
        _emailer.SendMail($"New Media for {dirName} is Available on Plex", $"{dirName} is available for viewing on Plex!");
        sentBy.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    #endregion`
```